# How do I mark a radio button as "checked" within my Blazor app, while creating the radio buttons inside of a foreach loop?

Tags: .net-core, blazor

I am populating a group of radio buttons in my Blazor app with a `foreach` loop:

```
Dictionary<string,string> my_radio_options = new Dictionary<string,string>(){
    {"optionone","Option One"}
    {"optiontwo","Option Two"}
    {"optionthree","Option Three"}
    {"optionfour","Option Four"}
    {"optionfive","Option Five"}
}

@foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> entry in my_radio_options) {
    <input type="radio" name="my_selected_option" id="my_selected_option-@entry.Value" @onclick="() => my_selection = entry.Key">
}

@code {
    private string my_selection;

    private void do_something() {
        // Use "my_selection" here ...
    }
}
```

I tried this:

```
<input type="radio" name="my_selected_option" id="my_selected_option-@entry.Value" @onclick="() => my_selection = entry.Key" checked="@(entry.Key.Equals(my_radio_options.ElementAt(1).Key) ? "checked" : "")">
```

And this:

```
@{bool first = true;}
@foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> entry in my_radio_options) {
    <input type="radio" name="my_selected_option" id="my_selected_option-@entry.Value" @onclick="() => my_selection = entry.Key" checked="@(first ? "checked" : "")">
    @(first = false)
}
```

However, neither one of those works.

How can I do this?

Comment: can you try like this:`<input type="radio" name="my_selected_option" id="my_selected_option-@entry.Value"  checked="@first">`

Comment: @TheBacker YES ... that worked! Thank you. It's weird, though, if I `F12` and inspect that element, I don't see "checked" or "checked='true'" or anything. Anyway, it works. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There's more than one way to do this, but here's a working version of your code.

1. `my_selection` can be either the key or the value, it depends on which you want.
2. C# code is not mixed up with the Razor markup - makes it easy to read.
3. `IsChecked` returns true/false.
4. Uses `onchange` event rather that `onclicked` which is more appropriate for buttons.

```
@page "/Check"
@foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> entry in my_radio_options)
{
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="my_selected_option" id="my_selected_option-@entry.Value" checked="@this.IsChecked(entry.Key)" @onchange="() => Update(entry.Key)">
        <label>@entry.Value</label>
    </div>
}
<div class="m-3">Selected item: @my_selection</div>

@code {
    private string my_selection = "optionthree";

    private void do_something()
    {
        // Use "my_selection" here ...
    }
    Dictionary<string, string> my_radio_options = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        {"optionone","Option One"},
        {"optiontwo","Option Two"},
        {"optionthree","Option Three"},
        {"optionfour","Option Four"},
        {"optionfive","Option Five"},
    };

    private void Update(string value)
    {
        my_selection = value;
    }

    private bool IsChecked(string value)
        => value.Equals(my_selection);
}
```